# convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x} dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

How can I show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x} dx}$ converges? I tried the criteria listed in my book but none seem to apply

Comment: Try using $\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=1-\frac2{x^2+1}$ and use different tests on each piece. (Dirichlet's Test)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals] might be useful.

Comment: As $x\to \infty,\ \frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\to1$, so the integrand can be compared to $\frac{sin(2x)}{x}$, which is a standard form.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_integrals) is for absolutely convergent integrals. Something a bit more is needed.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\frac{sin(2x)}{x}dx$ is not absolutely convergent.  You need to work with $\lim_{y\to \infty}\int_0^y\frac{sin(2x)}{x}dx$, which converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $${\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{x} -\frac 2 {x^2+1}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$$
Also, it's a known fact that $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x}dx$$
converges.
So all we have to prove is that

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac 2 {x^2+1}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}dx$$ converges.
This is because the integrand converges to 4 as $x\rightarrow 0$, and its absolute value is bounded by $\frac 4 {x^3}$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: No worries! Happens all the time to me